# ORACLE APEX: How to update all items in APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01 without a LOOP

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using checkboxes in an interactive report in my apex app. Say it renders a table `MY_TABLE` This table contains a `FLAG` column whose value is either `0 or 1`

In the report, the checkbox for each row is ticked if `FLAG=1`

```sql
APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2(
            p_idx => 1,
            p_value => lrg_name,
            p_attributes => DECODE(flag,1,'CHECKED', 'null'))
```

I want to allow the user to select or deselect any rows. After which I need to update the `FLAG` column in DB accordingly.
For e.g. if a user:

1. changed 2 rows (A1, A2) from **checked to unchecked**

- Need to Update `FLAG=0` for these 2 rows

2. changed 3 rows (B1,B2,B3) from **unchecked to checked**

- Need to Update `FLAG=1` for these 3 rows

I learned that `APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01` will only contain the values for rows where checkbox was checked. This means I can update the **B1,B2,B3** rows as they are present in the array but not **A1,A2**.

So, as a hack, what I do is:

1. set `FLAG=0` for all rows in `MY_TABLE`
2. Loop over `APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01` and set `FLAG=1`

```sql
BEGIN﻿
-- step 1
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET FLAG=0;

-- step 2
FOR I in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT
LOOP 
     UPDATE MY_TABLE 
     SET FLAG=1 
     WHERE LRG_NAME=APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i);
END LOOP;
END;
```

**Step2** above takes a lot of time if the list is long. It runs one update query for each row. How can I run one query that can update all rows at once?

I tried using `APEX_UTIL.TABLE_TO_STRING` but it didn't work for me:

```sql
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET FLAG=1 
WHERE LRG_NAME IN APEX_UTIL.TABLE_TO_STRING(APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01);
```

Comment: Is there an index on my_table.lrg_name that is being used ?

Comment: do you mean p_idx=>1 i.e f01.. I'm using that as you can see in the code. OR index on column LRG_NAME itself? It is a VARCHAR2 column so putting an index won't speed up. There is an index on another ID column that I do use but have not mentioned above for simplicity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with apex_item.checkbox is that it only has a value when checked, so you don't have enough info to know which rows have changed from checked to unchecked or the other way around. You can get around that by adding additional apex_item.hidden columns and using those in your pl/sql process to update.

That way you can optimize your pl/sql block to only update the rows that actually need changing. In your case, you always update *all* rows. The code below will only update changed rows.

Example:

Basic table with a flag column. I'm using apex_item.checkbox (not checkbox2) but that shouldn't matter.

```
-- create tables
create table so_checkbox (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint so_checkbox_id_pk primary key,
    name                           varchar2(100 char) not null,
    favorite_flag                  varchar2(1 char) not null
)
;

-- load data
 
insert into so_checkbox (id, name, favorite_flag ) values (1, 'Zero Data Loss Implementation', 'N');
insert into so_checkbox (id, name, favorite_flag ) values (2, 'DevOps Best Practices', 'N');
insert into so_checkbox (id, name, favorite_flag ) values (3, 'New Hire Training', 'N');
insert into so_checkbox (id, name, favorite_flag ) values (4, 'Corporate Network Upgrade', 'N');
insert into so_checkbox (id, name, favorite_flag ) values (5, 'Continuous Build', 'N');
```

Create an interactive report on this table with sql query:

```
select ID,
       NAME,
       APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX(1,id,CASE WHEN FAVORITE_FLAG = 'Y' THEN 'CHECKED' END)||
       APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(2,CASE WHEN FAVORITE_FLAG = 'Y' THEN id END) as favorite
  from SO_CHECKBOX
```

In the first column, 2 apex_item columns are concatenated. The first one is the checkbox (id 1), the 2nd one (hidden) is the current value of the checkbox (id 2). In the process that runs on submit each of the arrays are put in a variable of type `apex_t_varchar2` and then the pl/sql `MULTISET` statement can be used to identify the changed checkboxes.

```
DECLARE
  l_old_checked apex_t_varchar2 := apex_t_varchar2();
  l_new_checked apex_t_varchar2 := apex_t_varchar2();
  l_added apex_t_varchar2 := apex_t_varchar2();
  l_removed apex_t_varchar2 := apex_t_varchar2();
BEGIN
  FOR i in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP 
    apex_string.push(l_new_checked,APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i));
  END LOOP;
  FOR i in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F02.COUNT LOOP 
    apex_string.push(l_old_checked,APEX_APPLICATION.G_F02(i));
  END LOOP;
  l_added := l_new_checked MULTISET EXCEPT l_old_checked;
  l_removed := l_old_checked MULTISET EXCEPT l_new_checked;
  UPDATE so_checkbox SET favorite_flag = 'Y' WHERE id IN (SELECT column_value FROM table(l_added));
  UPDATE so_checkbox SET favorite_flag = 'N' WHERE id IN (SELECT column_value FROM table(l_removed));
END;
```

Comment: Removed loops for update statements

Comment: thanks this works perfectly!

Comment: Great to hear !

Comment: where did you learn about `apex_t_varchar2`?

Comment: ... no idea. Probably the documentation. It's in all of the examples in the docs for ```APEX_STRING```